# ngx-drag-drop - Cannot access 'DndDraggableDirective' before initialization

Tags: angular, ngx-drag-drop

I'm updating angular and it's dependencies to 13th version and encountered an issue with ngx-drap-drop package in jest tests. Previously it was on 2.0.0 version and now on 13.0.0. So I have a component which uses some directives from ngx-drag-drop package in component's html file.

When I run jest tests(v27.4) I see this error:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'DndDraggableDirective' before initialization`

which points to `DndModule` import in my test file:

`import { DndModule } from 'ngx-drag-drop'`

I import `DndModule` into `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, so this is not the case(BTW ngx-drag-drop v2.0.0 been throwing the error `Unexpected value 'DndModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's angular compiler issue (or not, I'm not sure) so for now I fixed it by mocking DndDraggableDirective and DndDropZoneDirective in my code.

Also I cloned ngx-drag-drop repo to try to fix the issue and I wasn't able to compile project on master branch. So, working on it.